# How to Obfuscating C# wpf app which used Localization Extension

Tags: wpf, localization, obfuscation

For multi language support in a C# application I used [The Localization Extension](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/).
I obfuscated the application for publishing, But application doesn't work and got error **"Strings resource not found."**
I think obfuscating cause this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this problem,in obfuscating, should exclude renaming Resources.